# Facebook Like Javascript SDK only works on localhost

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I am using FB Javascript SDK to check that a user *like* my page or not. It's works on `localhost` but when I upload this on Server the code does not works. My code is below:

```
    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'My App Id', // App ID

            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            var page_id = "My Page ID";
            if (response && response.authResponse) {
                var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
                var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+"and uid="+user_id;
                FB.Data.query(fql_query).wait(function(rows) {
                    if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                        alert('Liked');
                    } else {
                        alert('Not Liked');
                    }
                });
            } 
        });
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
    </script>
```

It works on `localhost` and show an Alert but not on Server

Comment: error log, did you check it?

Comment: i check the error log but there is no error

Comment: This is weird, JS doesn't need any extra software, it works every where! can you put a link where it doesn't work?

Comment: Check my code are there is any mistake or if possible then tell me the other way

Comment: There's no errors at all, it should work :) but your code doesn't check if the user has authenticated your app already!

Comment: i am doing this with magento but not works on server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your internet domain to your application sites whitelist.

1. Go to http://developers.facebook.com
2. Open YourApp **Settings**
3. **Add Platform**
4. Write your **Site URL**